# getting a 'str' object does not support item assignment error in python

Tags: python, string, floating-point, typeerror

i am trying to write to run this piece of code here but i am receiving a 'str' object does not support item assignment error

```
    for i in range(1, len(rows1)): # len(rows) is 90
        for j in range(rowsize): # rowsize is 13
            training_data[i][j] = float(training_data[i][j]) # 'str' object does not support item assignment
        training_instances.append(training_data[i])
```

`training_instances = []` is empty and `training_data` is a list of values I have parsed in from a file. 
The first 3 elements of `training_data` looks something like this:

`['14.37 1.96 2.4 16.9 113.0 3.95 3.49 0.24 2.58 7.8 0.86 3.46 1481.0 1', '12.26 1.74 2.13 19.0 80.0 1.65 2.23 0.37 1.33 3.6 1.0 3.17 510.0 2', '11.82 1.47 1.99 20.8 86.0 1.98 1.6 0.3 1.53 1.95 0.95 3.33 495.0 2']`

Could someone please explain to me why I am getting this error? I am a total newbie at Python and just want to get this assignment handed in. It was due a few hours ago yikes.

Comment: `training_data[i]` seems to be a string. you can't change an individual character in a string as it's immutable (`"123"[1] = "6"`). You'll have to create a new (*2D*) array and populate it as you iterate on the original one.

Comment: You're right that was the issue! I've created the 2D array now and everything's working now. Thanks CristiFati!

Comment: You whole data is a string in a list, see the `''` in your output of `training_data`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`training_data[0]` is the string `'14.37 1.96 2.4 16.9 113.0 3.95 3.49 0.24 2.58 7.8 0.86 3.46 1481.0 1'`. It's not a list as you're trying to treat it. You say you've parsed the data but you simply haven't. Perhaps you meant to call `.split()` as you were creating `training_data`?

Comment: Hey, you're right, I forgot to call .split()! I have parsed it in (properly this time) now and the error has disappeared. Thanks Alex!